# `ng build` Unterminated string literal

Tags: angular

I'm having trouble with building my Angular app all of the sudden.  When I run `ng build`, I get the following error pretty quickly:
[image]

However, when I run `ng build --verbose`, the build succeeds without any error.

When I change `optimization` to false for the production build, and I adjust the size budgets to get past that error, the build succeeds then too.

I'm not sure how to diagnose this issue further.  I'm assuming I've got some special character somewhere that shouldn't be there or something like that.  How do I go about finding where the issue is?  When the build fails, there is nothing in the dist folder for me to look at

Comment: do you have this variable in your code : deffered[i]

Comment: I've searched and I don't find it anywhere in my source code nor in node_modules folder